# How to create from object from a different controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I am trying to create a job board where users can sign in, browse for a job and apply for a job by filling out a job application form.

This is my design.

user.rb

```
has_many :job_applications
```

job.rb

```
has_many :job_applications
```

job_application.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :job
```

schema

```
create_table "job_applications"......|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "job_id"
.........
```

my `job_controller` has `index` and `show` methods.

On the `show.html.erb` job page, there is an **Apply For This Job** button linking to a custom apply method which is derived from a member route of the job resources.

```
<%=link_to'Apply For This Job', apply_job_path(@job),class:"btn btn-success btn-block"%>
```

Here are the job routes

```
resources: jobs do
  member do
    get :apply
  end
end
```

So, I want to have a form on the apply.html.erb page. that will take the user.id and job.id to create a job Application object for the current user

Here are my issues.

1. I don't know if my design is correct
2. How can I create a form that will save a new application for the current user including the job.id in the database under the `apply.html.erb` since this method is on a different controller

i need help to fill the `create` method in the `job_applications_controller`

```
class JobApplicationsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def create

    ## coded needed
  end
```

and to implement the form on the `apply.html.erb` page

Hope you understand

Thanks!

Comment: Your models layout looks like `has_many_through`, but it misses some relation. Read carefully this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association --- To create a `job_application` you need to save into `JobApplication` `user_id` and `job_id`. So, you can simply use the same form used in new or edit, placing it into apply view. In controller `def apply` similarly as `def new`. Consider the `user_id` field form to be hidden or get the `user_id` from elsewhere.

Comment: what form used in the new or edit are you talking about. The users can't create jobs. only the admin has such privileges

Comment: Of course. Just copy the logic. In `apply` action of `JobApplicationsController` you need to instantiate an object to be used in the form. As the standard `new` action in rails does.

Comment: I don't have any logic in the apply action. and the apply action is under the job controller  and not under job application controller

Comment: There is a bit of confusion. `link_to apply_job_path(@job)` calls the `apply` action in `jobs` controller. So you need the view `jobs\apply.erb`, this is where you want the form. **What are the form fields? And what action is calling the form?** Consider that once you know `current_user.id` you can create application right under `jobs#apply` action. But I'd move under `job_applications#apply`

Comment: yes, the form fields are the **user full name, address, interest in the job and phone number**. I want the form to call the job_application controller with the new and create action if that is possible and I want the create action to carry the current_user_id and the job_id.If I move the apply action to the job_application controller, waht will be the logic under the apply action, and what will be the link_to url on the **Apply For this Job**  link on the job show page. How will the system know that the user is applying for the job he is viewing on the show job page. How would you do it

Comment: Well, your question is really too broad. It depends on what experience you design for your users.
For example, if the user is already logged in, why do you ask for contact information again?
Why not placing the contact form directly in the job page? Etc. etc. I suggest you to imagine the flow you want then implement it. If you get stuck on implementing it, ask again.